# How to get array item in Selenium IDE and use it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium-ide

this is my code

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Array ('cat','dog')</td>
    <td>names</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['names'].length}</td>
    <td>length</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Math.floor((Math.random()*storedVars['length'])+0)</td>
    <td>rn</td>
</tr>
```

and here is where it doesnt work:

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=ProductName[2]</td>
    <td>javascript{names['1']}</td>
</tr>
```

this doesnt work as well
(i want to use a random item here):

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=ProductName[1]</td>
    <td>javascript{names[storedVars['rn']]}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This.
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Array ('cat','dog')</td>
    <td>names</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['names'].length}</td>
    <td>length</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{Math.floor(Math.random()*storedVars['length'])}</td>
    <td>num</td>
</tr>

For Adding values normaly

<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=ProductName[2]</td>
    <<td>javascript{storedVars['names'][0]}</td>
</tr>

For Adding values randomly
<tr>
    <td>type</td>


    <td>name=ProductName[2]</td>
    <<td>javascript{storedVars['names'][storedVars.num]}</td>
</tr>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
javascript{storedVars.names[storedVars.rn]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get array item in seleniun ide

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=ProductName[1]</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['names'][storedVars.rn]}</td>
</tr>
```